# Error in SPRING JPA using eclipse link POSTGRESQL when executing findBy[NAME]In(List<Long> ids)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I got a problem with my SPRING JpaRepository class when trying to use the findByIdIn(List ids), eg i want to pass a list of ids to the native query and expect it to return a list of objects.

Maven dep.:

- spring-data-jpa 1.4.2
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa 2.5.1

DB:

- PostgreSQL 9.3

Appserver:

- Glassfish 4.0

Here is my repository class

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Transaction> {

    List<Transaction> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
}
```

Field id in database is BIGINT.

When I pass ONLY 1 object in the list it works, when it's 0 or more than 1 object in the list I receive this error:

```
Local Exception Stack:

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = record
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 160
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, amount, comment, created_date, currency, status, transaction_step, transaction_type, version, provider_id, user_id FROM anix.transactions WHERE (ID IN ((?,?)))
    bind => [2, 3]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Transaction sql="SELECT ID, amount, comment, created_date, currency, status, transaction_step, transaction_type, version, provider_id, user_id FROM anix.transactions WHERE (ID IN (?))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
```

The SQL works fine in my admin tool if I copy/paste it there.

--- EDIT ---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions", schema = "anix")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class Transaction implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "transactions_sequence", sequenceName = "transactions_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "transactions_sequence")
    @XmlID
    @XmlElement
private Long id;
```

Would appreciate any help on this!

Regards

Comment: What is the type of the `id` field on the `Transaction` entity?

Comment: Edited post with id-def for field

Comment: What is the type of `id` in the database in the database?

Comment: Can u trying changing the JPA provider once? Like Hibernate or OPEN JPA?

Comment: Database field is bigint.

Comment: Post the query definition.

Comment: Show the query.  If it is native, it will not take a list as a parameter, so I don't think it's a native SQL query.

Comment: Ok, so i tried to follow the example given here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html
And the keywords allowed in table : Table 2.3. Supported keywords inside method names

Comment: The query definition is the method if I understood correctly: List<Transaction> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a BUG. See here: [DATAJPA-433](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-433) and here: [Bug 349477](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477)

Comment: Is there a workaround to this? Can i write a JPQL query?